# 'For' loop and sleep in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, sleep, kill

I have a Bash script with a `for` loop, and I want to sleep for X seconds.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 8`;
    do ssh w$i 'uptime;
    ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;
    free -m;
    mpstat';
done &
pid=$!
kill -9 $pid
```

In Bash: `sleep 2` sleeps for two seconds. How can I kill the pid automatically after two seconds?

Comment: Insert `sleep 2` before the `kill` line.

Comment: @devnull, that's not what he wants. He want to kill `for` if it takes too long, not wait 2 seconds after exec then kill it

Comment: @Samoth OP says kill it if the loop takes more than 2 sec.  `sleep 2` would do that precisely.  If the process has completed, `kill` would be a _no-op_ (chances of any other process acquiring the same PID would be slim).

Comment: @Samoth The `done &` line has a `&` in it that forks off the work of the for loop as a separate process.  That process is still running as the next lines execute.  Without a sleep, the child running the for loop would be killed immediately.

Comment: Could also make a wrapper and do `timeout 2 script`

Comment: @Paul you're right, I read `&&`, my bad !

Comment: `kill -9` is overkill; just `kill $pid` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like suggested in the comments

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 8`; 
    do ssh w$i 'uptime;
    ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;
    free -m;
    mpstat'; 
done &
pid=$!
sleep 2
kill -9 $pid
```

In this version, one ssh process may stay alive forever. So maybe it would be better to kill each ssh command separately:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 8`; 
    do ssh w$i 'uptime;
    ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;
    free -m;
    mpstat' &;
    pid=$!
    sleep 0.3
    kill $pid
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your loop in a wrapper:

**Your script** (I call it `foo.sh`)

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 8`; 
    do ssh w$i 'uptime;
    ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;
    free -m;
    mpstat'; 
done
```

**The wrapper**

```
#!/bin/sh
foo.sh &
pid=$!
sleep 3         #sleep takes number of seconds
kill $pid
```

You also can check if your process already exists by `ps -p $pid -o pid | grep $pid`